# Find out who deleted the row in the DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle

We have a Oracle DB with around  4K tables in it. And around 30 different applications accessing the data. We have an issue where one of the application is deleting a row in one of our tables. We do not know which app and why. I'm trying to figure out, but, first thought I got is to use Triggers when ever something is deleted and log it, but, is there a way to find out which application has deleted it in oracle?

Thanks

Comment: From within a trigger? `v$session` might tell you, if the application identifies itself properly, but it might just say something generic like JDBC; or you could get the session's IP address if the applications are on separate boxes. Have you considered the built-in auditing tools though?

Comment: With supplemental logging enabled it will be trivial to determine which user did what.

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm not an expert in Oracle, I'll research on the built-in auditing tools. I'm just looking for pointers as to where to start from. Please let me know if there is any other way in the answers. Thanks.

Comment: Are there different credentials for the different applications, or are they all connecting to the DB as the same user?

Comment: You could use the SYS_CONTEXT function inside your trigger to get information about the client http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm

Comment: @DavidConrad all applications use single datasource in weblogic so, that means they all have one login credentials

Comment: @GoatCO I see that supplemental logging only helps us during update, does it work when the row is deleted as well?

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use triggers to find out with all above info.

Comment: @AlexPoole how do I use the v$session? should I use it in a query? does it get me the app name that is accessing?

Comment: @6ton That does not bring all the information unfortunately.

Comment: [This might be useful too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25153787/266304). `v$session` (and related views) and `sys_context` can show similar information, but will only show the application name if it sets it, which I suspect is unlikely, and you'd just see JDBC. The stack trace might give you a clue. There's no magic bullet though.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt want to go down the autiting or logging route and the application is not distinct from v$session as it stands, you could set the name of the application by calling

`dbms_application_info.set_client_info('my_application');`

This sets v$session.client_info for the session, which you can read via

```
dbms_application_info.read_client_info(client_info out varchar2);.
```

You could then use triggers and to record this value.